# Typo3 6.2: +ext template

Tags: templates, typo3

I have a root template. It's very long and includes a lot of other templates. It was **not** written by me. Now, on a **sub**-page I have created an +ext template which overrides some code from the root template. It works just fine. The only problem is that my overriding is not passed on to the **sub**-**sub**-page. I thought templates were applied in the sub-tree by default?

Comment: Are there overwriting on sub-sub pages?

Comment: aside from cache: some aspects to consider: `conditions`, `order of includes`, `stdwrap.if`, multiple extension-templates (only one per page). check the resulting TS with TSOB and template analyzer

Comment: there's no template on the sub-sub-page. How are templates loaded? Does it go up the tree and load +ext first? That would explain, because then the root template would overwrite +ext. But this behaviour wouldn't make any sense to me...

Comment: the problem is gone, I think it was a caching problem ... classic :) sorry